# Different transformations having the same matrix representation with respect to two different bases.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Suppose $T$ and $U$ are two different linear transformations but there exists bases $\beta$ and $\beta'$ such that $[T]_{\beta}$=$[U]_{\beta'}$.Then we have an invertible matrix $P$ such that $[T]_{\beta}=P^{-1}[U]_{\beta}P$ and conversely.Now I want to know what does it exactly mean?What is the meaning of two different transformations having same representation with respect to two different bases.I want to understand what it actually mean,or what is physically its meaning.Is there any relation between this thing and change where we represent the same transformation with respect to two different bases.

Comment: Please take a look at [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity)

Comment: @Bio It is not matrix similarity,it is something different,it is two different transformations which have same matrix with respect to two different bases.

Comment: @Bio Are you there?